# Unique value Constraint with multiple columns across the table, not the combination in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns, unique-constraint

In oracle is there a way to enforce uniqueness among two columns?

Its not the uniqueness among combination of two columns, but values across table among two columns.

References:

[Unique value constraint across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628569/unique-value-constraint-across-multiple-columns)

Example data, which should not be allowed:

```
id | phone1 | phone2
1  | 111    | 111

id | phone1 | phone2
1  | 111    | NULL
2  | 111    | NULL  

id | phone1 | phone2
1  | 111    | NULL
2  | NULL   | 111
```

[Unique constraint on combination of two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613450/unique-constraint-on-combination-of-two-columns)

My Oracle Version:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and examples of what is and is not allowed.

Comment: I added references, which have the samples of what I am looking for.

Comment: So, `phone1` must not be the same as `phone2`, and any value should be unique across both columns?

Comment: Thats correct. Please check the 2nd and 3rd cases above for more info. In all, the value of any of these two fields (`phone1` and `phone2` should be unique among two columns values across the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `check()` constraint to ensure unicity on each row, and a unique index for unicity across rows:

```
create table mytable (
    id int, 
    phone1 int, 
    phone2 int,
    check (phone1 <> phone2)
);

create unique index myidx on mytable(
    greatest(coalesce(phone1, phone2), coalesce(phone2, phone1)),
    least(coalesce(phone1, phone2), coalesce(phone2, phone1))
);
```

The upside of this approach is that it also prevents inserts of tuples like `(111, 222)` and `(222, 111)`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9f86e9ac558e81633e9364c8c1bbf8f)**:

```
insert into mytable values(1, 111, 111);
```

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (FIDDLE_SMBYKTEIHNNVOHKZSCYK.SYS_C0020876) violated
```

```
begin
    insert into mytable values(1, 111, null);
    insert into mytable values(1, 111, null);
end;
/
```

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_SMBYKTEIHNNVOHKZSCYK.MYIDX) violated
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

```
begin
    insert into mytable values(1, 111, null);
    insert into mytable values(1, null, 111);
end;
/
```

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_SMBYKTEIHNNVOHKZSCYK.MYIDX) violated
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

```
begin
    insert into mytable values(1, 111, 222);
    insert into mytable values(1, 222, 111);
end;
/
```

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_SMBYKTEIHNNVOHKZSCYK.MYIDX) violated
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Comment: Your `greatest`/`least` construct is basically sorting the tuple, right?

Comment: @wolφi: yes, indeed. This is meant to prevent "mirror" tuples (the last use case in my answer).

Comment: What phones do you have??? ;-)  Yes, of course does it work with alpha-numeric...

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve it with a combination of a check constraint and a unique index on a function:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id NUMBER, phone1 NUMBER, phone2 NUMBER);
ALTER  TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT c1 CHECK (phone1 <> phone2);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u ON t(COALESCE(phone1, phone2));
```

Case 1 works:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 111, 111);
ORA-02290: check constraint (C1) violated
```

Case 2 works, too:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 111, NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 111, NULL);
ORA-00001: unique constraint (U) violated
```

Case 3, as well:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 111, NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, NULL, 111);
ORA-00001: unique constraint (WFL.U) violated
```

However, this is not protected:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 111, 222);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 222, 111);
```

Comment: Got it. But the last one is important.

Comment: OK, that's +1 for GMB's solution then.